# May I store array inside a html element and than use it as an array again

Tags: javascript

I have to store array in html element, so I can use it later.

I want to get --> arrayFromHtml[0] as [0,1] -->  arrayFromHtml[1] as [1,2]

```html
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
  var array = [
    [0, 1],
    [1, 2],
    [1, 2]
  ];
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = array;

  // than in another code block, i want to use array as

  var useStoredArray = function(arrayFromHtml) {
    console.log(arrayFromHtml[0]);
  }
  useStoredArray(document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML);
</script>
```

Comment: By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Comment: If you would like to delete your account you can go to your profile and request deletion. It might mean some of your posts get deleted too, but we do not allow users to vandalise or delete useful posts. Please, do not offend other people and do not bring any political agenda to Stack Overflow. We are all about content here, not the users.

Comment: We can vote however we like. That is what voting means. Would you like people to stop upvoting too? I recommend you switch your computer off and take a walk or read a book. Try to relax. You seem to be taking internet points too personally.

Comment: Only the person who submitted that downvote can tell you that, and you are probably not reaching them through your comments here. You can ask on [meta] if you really want to understand what happened here but chances are you will not like the experience. A better approach is to read old similar questions on meta, like https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285209/why-what-i-asked-was-downvoted (just a quick random Google hit)

Answer (score 3):

Not like that

You can use JSON.stringify and data attributes

That is assuming you WANT to show `0,1,1,2,1,2` but want to store
`[[0,1],[1,2],[1,2]]`

```html
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
  var array = [
    [0, 1],
    [1, 2],
    [1, 2]
  ];
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = array;
  document.getElementById("demo").dataset.storedarr = JSON.stringify(array);
  // than in another code block, i want to use array as

  var useStoredArray = function(obj) {
    const arrayFromHTML = JSON.parse(obj.dataset.storedarr);
    console.log(arrayFromHTML[0]);
  }
  useStoredArray(document.getElementById("demo"));
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you this works.  But other answer was more simple to use. So I marked it as answer.

Comment: Simpler does not mean better. My suggestion is the recommended way. I have one more line of code!?!?

Comment: Every one has an own world. So in my world. This one is usefull.

array = JSON.stringify(results.features[i]);
resultItems += "<tr onclick='poligonCiz(" + array + ")'>";

I asked my question to stackoverflow community in different and simpler way to get an answer.

dataset.storedarr not needed for my work.

Comment: I think Stackoverflow should allow two or more green accepted answers.

Comment: Your inline array is very inefficient and error prone. One surprise quote will break your onclick

Answer (score 2):

You should store the stringified array, then parse the array to retrieved items. Also, instead of `innerHTML` I will suggest you to use [`innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText) or [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) when get/set plain text (not *htmlString*):

```html
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
  var array = JSON.stringify([[0,1], [1,2], [1,2]]);
  document.getElementById("demo").textContent = array;

  var useStoredArray = function(arrayFromHtml){ 
    console.log(JSON.parse(arrayFromHtml)[0]);
  }
  useStoredArray(document.getElementById("demo").textContent);
</script>
```